# Login con php y sql server

Tags: php

Cuando entro a mi pagina me aparece error en las variables de `$usuario` y `$contraseña`, me dice que no existe pero cuando hago click en el submit se desaparece aunque no sea el usuario y contraseña correcta. aparece este error `Undefined index: usuario`.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
        $serverName = "localhost";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"GRR", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"fdg");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];


        if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['contrasena'])){
        echo " ";
        }else{


        $query = "SELECT USUARIO, CONTRASENA FROM LOGIN WHERE USUARIO='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

        if($result === false){
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }


        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
            echo "usuario/contrasena no encontrada";
        }else{


        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $row['contrasena'];
        }

        header("Location: index.php");
        }
        }



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

según la [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-has-rows?view=sql-server-2017) para la función *sqlsrv_has_rows* el valor de retorno es **true** o **false**, la comparación que haces dentro del if no siempre va a ser correcta y puedes tener un bug.

Adicionalmente creo que necesitas darle la opción de "session_start()" al inicio del script ya que estas llamando variables de sesión dentro del while.

Por último, te recomiendo que migres tu código a PDO para evitar ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)